# Yii2 yii\data\ActiveDataFilter and pagination false

Tags: php, yii2

I have configured the yii2 restapi in module.

Now for setting pagination to false and to add filter I added the code like:

```
public function actions()
    {
        $actions = parent::actions();
        unset($actions['create'], $actions['update'], $actions['delete']);

    $actions['index'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\IndexAction',
        'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
        'checkAccess' => [$this, 'checkAccess'],

        'prepareDataProvider' => function () {

            $model = new $this->modelClass;
            $query = $model::find();

            $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => $query,
                'pagination' => false,

            ]);
            return $dataProvider;
        },
    ]; 
    $actions['index']['dataFilter'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\data\ActiveDataFilter',
        'searchModel' => 'app\models\TimeTableSearch'
    ];
    return $actions;
}
```

but filtering doesn't work, but if I comment out or remove `$action['index']` array, filtering works fine, but my setting of pagination false stops working.

how I can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing your filter to data provider. It should be something like this (not tested):

```
'prepareDataProvider' => function ($action, $filter) {
    $model = new $this->modelClass;
    $query = $model::find();
    if (!empty($filter)) {
        $query->andWhere($filter);
    }

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => false,

    ]);
    return $dataProvider;
},
```

Comment: Thanks Bizley - it works just fine. can you help me understand that, `function($action, $filter)` from where  the function is getting the `$filter` value also I am able to filter like `api/time-table/filter[id]=5` but I want it to work like `api/time-table/?id=5`, is it possible?

Comment: I guess... Configuration for this might be tricky - you would have to do some URL rewriting or UrlManager special rules or maybe extract that action to be a standard controller's action (inline) and play with the action parameters. Definitely not something available as it is.